# problemas ao executar android usb no android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Alguém sabe porque tá dando esse erro não consigo executar a aplicação nem no meu smartphone com modo de depuração ativado e nem com o emulador?
alguém sabe, sou novo no android e queria fazer uma aplicação para meu site se alguém puder me ajudar fico grato.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que [isto](http://bfy.tw/5NxE) ajuda. Esta pergunta já foi respondida em inglês. Verifique-a!

Answer (score 1):

O emulador não vai rodar porque você configurou para que a versão minima da API seja maior que a versão que vai rodar no emulador. Posta o seu build.gradle, por favor.

Seu celular não está aparecendo ai porque você tem que desbloquear ele quando conecta no computador pro Android Studio reconhecer ou o cabo/celular/entrada está com algum problema.

Comment: já resolvi o problema estou utlizando o emulador genymotion para rodar as aplicações